# Using a main class / function defined in a jar file

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I'm trying to create the following setup in a Java NetBeans project:

- Jar with a main class and main function.
- Create a project that use this jar and just add their own specifics (i.e. some classes are going to be missing from the jar and its up for the project to add those classes).

The jar is running OK by itself (although the classes that are eventually going to be removed are still there).

I'm trying to create the project that will "use" the jar.

I did the setup and put the Jar file in the "Libraries" configuration (in the Project Properties).

After this, the project structure became like this:

```
> MyJavaApp
>> Source Packages
>>> <default package>
>> Librares
>>> The-Lib-From-The-Jar
>>>> <default package>
>>>>> MyJar.jar
>>>>>> mypackage
>>>>>>> AppViewer.class
```

MyJavaApp is the name of the project that uses the Jar. MyJar is the name of the Jar. The AppViewer.class is the one that is supposed to start everything up (this class is declared as public).

When trying to execute the project, I got this error:

> Project MyJavaApp does not have a main class set.

Then I went back to the project properties, specifically to the "Run" configuration, and defined the following:

> Main class: mypackage.AppViewer.class

After doing this, I get the following message when attempting to execute the project:

> The class mypackage.AppViewer.class wasn't found in MyJavaApp project.

I tried other variants:

> Main class: mypackage.AppViewer
>
> Main class: AppViewer

with the same results.

I'm looking for some tips on how to do the proper configuration for the above mentioned setup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did I get your problem ? You have a JAR included in an APP. You want to start the APP with the Main from the JAR ?

Comment: Yes. The idea is that the Jar is the actual app, but with missing classes, that must be implemented by the person creating the second project (that will use the Jar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its now working.

Before, I had clicked on the dist folder (expecting to expand it in order to select the .jar file), but instead of expanding the folder, NetBeans placed the whole folder under the Libraries branch of the project tree:

```
>> Libraries
>>> The-Path-To-Lib-From-The-Jar
>>>> <default package>
>>>>> MyJar.jar
```

I went back to the configuration, and instead of clicking on the folder, I wrote the full path to the .jar file, the project structure looks like this:

```
>> Libraries
>>> MyJar.jar
>>>> mypackage
>>>>> AppViewer.class
```

Note that there are 2 less levels on the tree.

After doing this, when I click on AppViewer.class I get the signatures of the methods (which previously were not there) so I suppose the previous method was not actually placing the .jar in the compilation structure.

Thanks.